# Spanish visa for non-EU spouse

Tags: visa, marriage, eu-spouses, documentation

My husband went to the Spanish Embassy today to submit a visa application in accordance with the EU directive, since I am a European living in Spain.
However, he was denied because we don't have a European marriage certificate. What can we do in this case?

Comment: Where were you married and did the embassy say they don't believe your certificate is a genuine document?

Comment: What marriage documents do you have?

Comment: What is your husband's nationality? And where did you get married?